# BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe socket python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, c++, socket, debian

estoy haciendo un script en python para enviar archivos a un servidor en C++, con archivos pequeños, hasta los 50MB, pero cuando pruebo a pasar archivos de 3GB aproximadamente, me salta el error BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe. Os adjunto el código del cliente:

```
import socket
import time as t
import math as m

class enviar():
    def __init__(self):
        #Creamos la conexión
        self.emisor=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        ip='localhost'
        puerto=9999
        #Conectamos
        self.emisor.connect((ip,int(puerto)))
        
        ls=[]
        
        #Enviamos archivo
        a='archivo.zip'
        archivo=open(a, "rb")
        contenido=archivo.read()
        archivo.close()        
        
        #Enviamos el nombre del archivo junto a la longitud del nombre
        self.emisor.send(str(len(a)).encode('UTF-8'))
        t.sleep(1)
        self.emisor.send(a.encode("UTF-8"))
        t.sleep(1)
        
        #Enviamos la longitud del archivo
        self.emisor.send(str(len(contenido)).encode('UTF-8'))
        t.sleep(1)
        
        #Enviamos el contenido del archivo
        for i in range(len(contenido)):
            ls.append(contenido[i*1:(i+1)])
            #Me salta el error cuando llega a esta parte
            self.emisor.send(ls[0])                
            del(ls[0])
        self.emisor.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enviar()
```

Y aquí os adjunto el código del servidor en C++:

```
char* memoria;//Puntero donde almacenaremos el mensaje
    double* paquetes;//Creamos un puntero donde guardaremos el numero de paquetes que se reciben
    
    //Esperamos que se reciba datos desde el CLIENTE, en caso que se reciba 0 se producira un error, guardo lo recibido en BUFFER
    if(recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,this->BUFFER,100,0)<0){cout<<"Se ha producido un error, se cierra la conexion"<<endl;close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);}
    else{
        cout<<"Se ha recibido: "<<this->BUFFER<<endl;
        bzero((char*)&memoria,sizeof(memoria));//Llenamos de 0 todo el puntero memoria
        memoria=new char[atoi(this->BUFFER)];//Reservamos espacio en la memoria para recibir el mensaje
        recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,memoria,atoi(this->BUFFER),0);//Recibimos el mensaje
        cout<<"El mensaje reicbido es: "<<memoria<<endl;
        close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);
        
        //Creamos el archivo
        Arch=new Archivo(atoi(this->BUFFER));
        Arch->Crear(memoria);
        
        recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,this->BUFFER,100,0);//Recibimos el numero de paquetes que se necesitan
        paquetes=new double(atoi(this->BUFFER));//Guardamos el numero de paquetes
        
        delete[] memoria;//Liberamos la memoria usada para el nombre    
        
        
        for(double i=0;i<*paquetes;i++){
            
            
            memoria=new char[LONGITUD];//Reservamos un nuevo espacio en la memoria
            recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,memoria,LONGITUD,0);//Recibimos el paquete
            Arch->Contenido(memoria);//Vertimos el contenido del mensaje sobre el fichero
            delete[] memoria;//Liberamos la memoria
            
        }
        
        Arch->Cerrar();//Cerramos el archivo
        delete Arch;//Liberamos la memoria que usaba Arch
```

Y el código del método Contenido de la clase Archivo:

```
inline void Archivo::Contenido(char* contenido){
    
    /*
    
        Añadimos contenido al archivo que habiamos creado
    
    */
    
    cout<<++this->CONTADOR<<" Bytes"<<endl;
    
    fputc(*contenido,this->ARCHIVO);
};
```

Y os agradezco por adelantado su tiempo, un saludo.

PD: Dudo que sirva de algo, pero uso como sistema operativo Debian 10.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código Python lee el archivo completo a memoria antes de enviarlo:

```
archivo = open(a, "rb")
contenido = archivo.read()
archivo.close()
```

Eso funciona con archivos pequeños, pero dudo que puedas cargar +3GB. En todo caso, como practica no es recomendable.

Luego envias el archivo (que ya está en memoria), caracter a caracter, lo cual
es sumamente lento e ineficiente. La forma correcta de hacerlo es procesar linea a linea o en bloques tan grandes como se pueda.

Para averiguar el tamaño del archivo, usamos `os.path.getsize`, que retorna el tamaño en bytes.

```
    tamano = os.path.getsize(nombre_archivo)
```

Luego leemos y enviamos:

```
    # Enviamos la longitud del archivo
    tamano = os.path.getsize(a)
    self.emisor.send(str(tamano).encode('UTF-8'))
    # Enviamos el contenido del archivo
    archivo = open(a, "rb")

    for linea in archivo:
        self.emisor.send(linea)

    archivo.close()
    self.emisor.close()
```

Comment: @ Candid Moe Acabo de probar la solución que me has proporcionado, y me funciona perfectamente a la hora de enviar los datos y es bastante mas practico que cargar el archivo en la ram, y luego enviarlo byte a byte. Pero me ocurre una cosa, cuando me pongo a enviar los datos me sale al rato ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.

Comment: He estado leyendo y al parecer se debe a que el servidor se ha visto sobrepasado por el numero de peticiones y se ha caído la conexión. Para solucionar esto que tendría que poner ¿Un time.sleep(X), para que no se sobrecargue el servidor en `for linea in archivo:   self.emisor.send(linea)`?

Comment: @pablogac. Te sugiero que hagas una nueva pregunta partiendo de la versión actual: "¿Por qué tengo Connection Reset en esta app?". Completa el código de la parte servidor (C++) para poder probar.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias por su ayuda.